# Authorization Code with Proof Key token request results in invalid client response

Tags: oauth, openid, identityserver3, appauth

I'm currently evaluation AppAuth (https://appauth.io/) for use in a native mobile app together with a STS which currently uses IdentityServer3. I've configured a client like this:

```cs
new IdentityServer3.Core.Models.Client
{
    Enabled = true,
    ClientId = "app",
    ClientName = "app",
    ClientUri = "app:/",
    Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCodeWithProofKey,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RequireSignOutPrompt = false,
    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 28800,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "app:/signin"
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "app:/signout"
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
                StandardScopes.OpenId.Name.Name,
                StandardScopes.Email.Name.Name,
                StandardScopes.Profile.Name.Name,
                StandardScopes.Roles.Name.Name,
                StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
    }
}
```

The initial authorize request succeeds and IdentityServer3 returns an authorization code. Now I tried a subsequent token request, and this results in an HTTP 400 with an invalid_client error and the following messages in the IdentityServer3 log:

```
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Information] Start token request
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Debug] Start client validation
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Debug] Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Debug] Start parsing for secret in post body
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Debug] No secret in post body found
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Debug] Start parsing for X.509 certificate
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Debug] X.509 certificate not found.
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Information] Parser found no secret
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Information] No client secret found
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Information] End token request
2018-04-17 10:16:38.324 +02:00 [Information] Returning error: invalid_client
```

Do I understand something wrong or why doesn't IdentityServer3 return an access token?

Comment: have you set `code_challenge` in the authorize request and `code_verifier` in the token request?

Comment: Yes. I set `code_challenge` in the authorize request which returned an authorization code. I also set the `code_verifier` in the token request, which resulted in an invalid client response as stated.

Comment: I just tried @Kahbazi 's suggestion. After adding a client secret to the configuration of the client in IdSrv3 and additionally setting the Authorization header at the token request I get an id and access token.

Comment: yes but odd that you should need a client secret for this flow. See : https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/25

Comment: Seem's like it's an IdentityServer3 issue https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/issues/304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to authenticate `Client` in token request for `Authorization Code` flow. So you need to set `ClientSecrets` for your client.

```
new IdentityServer3.Core.Models.Client
{
    /// your properties

    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    }
}
```

And you need to send `client_secret` as a query string in your token request.

Or you can use `BasicAuthentication`. In this case you need to add `Base64(ClientId:ClientSecret)` in authentication header.

Comment: I just tried this and it seem's to work. What I don't understand is why the client secret is needed? PKCE is used for public clients, where a client secret doesn't make sense anyway.